# New SP version coming?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Problem:
When is a new version of SharePoint will be released in the market? What do you think guys from your experience?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint typically runs on 3 year cycles with each new version coming out in the fall of the year before it's namesake.  That is, based on the past three iterations, the most likely date for SharePoint 2016 will be fall of 2015.

This is only a guess though as Microsoft has been pushing for more aggressive release schedules on its products.

Comment: And if we talk office 365, the 16 version is already rolled out in beta to some tenants, really marking the new more continuos releases in the cloud